# How to choose function $\sum_{m\in \mathbb Z} (-1)^m f(x+m) f(x-m+n)=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Can we expect to choose a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (nonzero compactly supported) so that

> $\sum_{m\in \mathbb Z} (-1)^m f(x+m) f(x-m+n)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$  and $n\in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: This seems interesting. Could you provide a bit motivation (context)? How did you encounter this problem? Is it en route to solving something else?